# android-studio widget problem react-native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i am trying to run build, but i'm getting this error: '11:13: AAPT: error: resource android:dimen/system_app_widget_internal_padding not found.'

```
Having themes.xml for v31 variant because @android:dimen/system_app_widget_background_radius
 and @android:dimen/system_app_widget_internal_padding requires API level 31
```

```
<style name="Theme.AppWidget.AppWidgetContainerParent" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.DayNight">
        <item name="appWidgetRadius">@android:dimen/system_app_widget_background_radius</item>
        <item name="appWidgetPadding">@android:dimen/system_app_widget_internal_padding</item>
        <item name="appWidgetInnerRadius">@android:dimen/system_app_widget_inner_radius</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete related themes and styles, usually under the path: "values-night-v31" and "values-v31"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).